# Create Eleements from nested object. (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know this might be a simple question but I have to loop through an array,  for each element I create dom elements with react but if the element is also an array I need to repeat the process until there is no nested arrays left.

example array:

```
[el1, el2, [el1, [el1, el2], el4 ]
```

expected output

```
<div className={el1}/> ... </div>
<div className={el2}/> ... </div>
<div className={el3}/> 
  <div className={el1}/> ... </div>
  <div className={el2}/>
     <div className={el1}/> ... </div>
     <div className={el1}/> 
        <div className={el1}/> ... </div>
        <div className={el1}/> ... </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div className={el4}/> ... </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be recursive :)

For each item, check if it is an array or not and either render it as an array or a leaf element.

```
const Array = ({ array } => {
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? <Array array={e} /> : <Element element={e} />}
    </div>
  )
})

const Element = ({ element } => {
  return (
    <div>
      {element}
    </div>
  )
})
```